# Effects of Red vs. Green ambient lighting on sleep

Tags: sleep, color

I would like to know if there has been study on the difference of effect of red vs green ambient light on human sleep. This is specifically in the interest of choosing between red or green alarm clock digits.

I have found a similar study that compares green and blue, but not green and red: https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/06/160608154233.htm

Because green is an inhibitory signal to our brains, I would expect it would be better for sleep, but I personally find red to be feel the least intense, so I’d like to know if any study has been done.